# Navbar toggle collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Why my button doesn't want to work when browser window collapsed? I mean once hamburger menu button is clicked no menu appears.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar style available in Bootstrap framework-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- /end-->
      <!-- Anything that has to be responsive we are going to keep inside the Bootstrap grid -->
      <div class="container">
        <!-- /end -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="btnnavbar">
      <!-- For screen readers only -->
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <!-- /end -->
       <!-- Hamburger menu button appears when browser window has been shrinked -->
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- /end -->
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://codepen.io/ekilja01"><img id="imgbrand" src="http://www.kiljakandweb.com/favicon.png" alt="brand logo"></a>

        </div>
```

I guess everyone is fine until this point

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active" id="btnhome"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a8dfmy97/)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman http://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/pEXLNY doesn't work on codepen. I'm currently doing project at Free Code Camp. Code pen is chosen platform.

Comment: You haven't added jQuery and bootstrap.js. Add them and it will work.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Thank you indeed! Much appreciated! Can I please ask you one more question? Do you know that dropdown part that appears once I click on hamburger-menu button. How can I change transparency on that?

Comment: By inspecting the element `.navbar`, you will see that it is having `background-color` property. You can override it with any valid color value that you want.

Comment: Once again thanks very much!